# Website Booking Form does not send to email using php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, form-submit

ok i edited some of the code and the submit button does what i want it to do which is post my php file. However even if i get errors like i left a required field blank it will still submit the form now heres the new code i changed to

```
      onSubmit: function(invalid, event) {
    event.isDefaultPrevented();
    if (invalid) {
} else {
  $.post('save.php', this.$form.serialize(), function(response) {  
    // do something with response
  }, 'json');
}    
        $('#invalid')
          .show()
          .toggleClass('valid', ! invalid)
          .text(invalid ? (invalid +' invalid fields') : 'All good!');
      }
    });
```

How do i code this so that it only submits my form when there are no invalid fields

Comment: avoid sending mail from mail().

Comment: Why avoid `mail()`? It works very well if no missconfiguration in php.ini. A more useful hint is to avoid using error suppression `@`. How does OP expect an error message if it is suppressed..

Answer (score 1):

Dont use mail() function of php it will send your mail to junk only. Instead use SMTP php mailer function.

**Why we should use SMTP instead PHP mail():**

**SMTP** log in to an actual account on a mailserver and send the mail through SMTP to another mail server. If the mail server is configured correctly, your mails are sent from an actual account on a mailserver and will not wind up flagged as spam.

**Mail** sent with the mail() function is sent with sendmail in most cases. There is no authentication going on and it will almost always be flagged as spam if you use the "From:" in the extra headers.

This is because if you take a look at an original email file in say, gmail, you will see the headers that are sent. You are actually sending from user@serverhostname.tld and not someone@example.com like you had told the mail function to do.
If you use SMTP and view the original the email is actually sent from someone@example.com

You can download SMTP class from:

1. https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/trunk/class.smtp.php?r=170
2. http://www.phpclasses.org/package/14-PHP-Sends-e-mail-messages-via-SMTP-protocol.html

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

also declare all your variables at top of page

Comment: i have yes. the form sends fine if i remove this part of the script
  onSubmit: function(invalid, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (invalid) {
    alert(invalid +' fields!');
    } else {
    $.post('save.php', this.$form.serialize(), function(response) {  
// do something with response
      }, 'json');
    } 

But then it wont show my invalid fields and send the contact form as a blank

Comment: can u share your full form code and js, so I can test it on my side

Comment: if i give u the website link im testing this on  will you be able to check there.
http://pumzo.com/check/

Comment: can u share the php bit too please

Comment: pumzo.com/check/save.php

Answer (score 0):

$email seems not to be declared

Comment: As stated to another user when i remove the following part of the script   onSubmit: function(invalid, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (invalid) {
    alert(invalid +' fields!');
    } else {
    $.post('save.php', this.$form.serialize(), function(response) {  
// do something with response
      }, 'json');
    }


Then the form sends perfectaly clear but wont show any invalid field i have